# Finding the position of a word in a string with the word repeating

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
words = sentence.split(' ')
if keyword in words:
    pos = words.index(keyword)
    pos = 0+1
    print(pos)
```

Right, so this is what i have but if the word repeats then it only shows the first position. Any ideas?

Comment: Your expected results are not clear to me, could you show what output you were expecting?

Comment: Hint: `index` has an optional `start` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
words = sentence.split(' ')
for (i, subword) in enumerate(words):
    if (subword == keyword): 
        print(i+1)
```

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks. Dont suppose you know how to put an error message in if they ask for a word  thats not in the sentence

Answer (score 0):

```
one liner with Counter

from collections import Counter
import re

s = "A sunny day, or rainy day"
# first split. Counter will find frequencies. most_common(1) will
# find repeating word and its frequency (2 in this case). 
# [0][0] will extract the word from Counter tuple, and put it into rindex
# as argument. 
print(s.rindex(Counter(re.split(r'[ ,]',s)).most_common(1)[0][0]))

22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version, more closely following your original style.

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
words = sentence.split(' ')

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    if keyword == word:
        print(i+1)  # if you want the index to start at 1, not 0
```

the Python [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function returns both the index of your word, as well as the word itself.

Answer (score -1):

This is how to do the code but with an error message on the end if a word is not in the sentence

```
 sentence= input("Please Enter A Sentence With No Puncatuation:> ")
 sentence= sentence.lower()
 keyword= input("Please Input A Word From The Sentence:> ")
 keyword= keyword.lower()
 words= sentence.split(' ')
 for (i, subword) in enumerate(words):
     if(subword == keyword):
        print(i+1)
        break
 else:
     print("Error This Word Isnt In The Sentence")
```

This Code Is Also Case Insensitive So You Can Do it In what ever Case